# QAction keyboard shortcut doesn't work with Qt designer

Tags: qt, keyboard-shortcuts, designer

I would like to use the *Space* shortcut for a *QAction*.

It works fine if I define it manually:

```
QAction *action = new QAction("test", this);
action->setShortcut(tr("Space"));

this->addAction(action);

this->connect(action, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(on_action_triggered()));
```

If I want to specify this shortcut from the designer, it doesn't work:

[image: action properties]

It doesn't work neither for all single letter shortcut (A, B, C, ...). If I use modifier (ie : Ctrl+A) it works fine.

Comment: Works fine for me. You can try change value of "shortcutContext" property of the action in Designer's properties table.